# django dynamic filtering does not return expected result

Tags: django-views, django-queryset

Following code does not return the expected results:

```
def getAssignedRoutes( request ):

search = request.POST.get('search', None)
rtgwfSelectRoutes = SelectRoute.objects.exclude(status='rtg_wf_resp').order_by('-created')

if search is not None and len(search.strip()) > 2:
    rtgwfSelectRoutes.filter(correlation_id__icontains=search.strip())

return render(request,'select_tool/assignedRoutes.html',{'rtgwfSelectRoutes': rtgwfSelectRoutes})
```

rtgwfSelectRoutes returns all the records without filtering the search. What is wrong?

Comment: When you test it, print the value of search right before the if statement. Also, print the evaluation of the if statement (`print bool(search is not None and len(search.strip()) > 2`). What are the two print results?

Comment: print return true and the count on rtgwfSelectRoutes is the same in both cases

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: as filter returns something, you have to assign it to a variable like:

```
rtgwfSelectRoutes = rtgwfSelectRoutes.filter(correlation_id__icontains=search.strip())
```

and now it works like expected ;)